# How do I display the total for specific items ordered in php

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm creating a food menu to practice PHP and SQL databases. In my database I have food names and given prices for those foods. In my table I have a number input box that asks the users to enter a quantity for the amount of food they want. What I'm trying to do is if I only order 1 pizza and one order of Fries how do I get the total to be displayed after the user clicks the submit button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        table,
        tr,
        th,
        td {
            border: solid 1px black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo '<form action="">';
        echo"<h1>Food Menu</h1>";
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","FoodMenu") or die("Missing Input. Go back and enter ID or Name");
        $query = "select productname,price from product" ;
        $r= mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        echo"<p></p>";
        echo"<table>";
        echo"<tr><th>product</th><th>price</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
            printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $row["productname"],$row["price"], '<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="0" min="0" max="5">');

        }
        echo"</table>";
        echo '<p><input type="submit">';
        echo '</form>';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my database info

```sql
CREATE TABLE product ( 
productname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 price double NOT NULL, )
INSERT INTO product (productname, price) VALUES 
('Pizza', 3.99), 
('Fries', 1.99), 
('water', 0.99), 
('Cheese Balls', 2.99), 
('Hot Dog', 2.99);
```

Comment: Form should has an action href link where you'll do all of requested calculations and then print a new view page with resultant values. Also add a method/type attribute to the form like POST or GET. Otherwise, you can use something similar to $.post / $.get / $.ajax via jQuery and skip submittion at all.

Answer (score 0):

Notes - in the following line, i removed the id from the quantity input because you'll have a number of these inputs and if they have IDs - each ID should be unique. You don't need it at all right now, so I removed it. Also, we need to add something like a class so we can grab the price and item name in the process. Here is that line rewritten:

```
 printf("<tr class='product'><td class='productName'>%s</td><td class='price'>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $row["productname"],$row["price"], '<input type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="0" min="0" max="5">');
```

Your form tag should have an onsubmit method which will call a javascript function to calculate, then display the total.

```
<form onsubmit='return doCalculation()'>
<!-- when you put a return statement in the onsubmit, we can return 'false' and as a result the form won't submit. For this example, we're not submitting the form, just doing the calculation -->
```

The script will look something like this

```
<script>
function doCalculation() {

var itemsOrdered='', total = 0, grandTotal =0, priceNumber;
// loop through product tr's 
var prods = document.getElementsByClassname('product');
prods.forEach(prod => {
// in here, prod is the tr element, so when we use it to find a classname it will only search inside that tr tag
var productName = prod.getElementsByClassName("productName")[0];
var price = prod.getElementsByClassName("price")[0];
var quantity = parseInt(prod.getElementsByClassName("quantity")[0].value);

if (quantity > 0) {
// we have a quantity, so add this to the list
priceNumber = Number(price.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,"")); // remove the $ and make sure it's a number
total = quantity * priceNumber;
grandTotal += total
  itemsOrdered += '<p>You ordered ' + quantity + ' ' + productName + '(s) for a total of $ ' + total + '</p>';
}
});

document.getElementById('itemsOrdered').innerHtml = itemsOrdered;
```

}

```
<div id='itemsOrdered'></div>
```